# How to optimize resources usage in Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

[image]

My website is showing the above error so many times. I contacted to server Hosting Technical support. they said, there is no available memory free to handle the new requests, that's why sometimes a 503 error is returned.

[image]

I want to optimize resource usage. how can i check the memory usage contains. which files & modules are using more memory & swap memory. how can i optimize them.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the a special file used by Magento to temporary lock the access to the site during maintenance operations. This files is called: **maintenance.flag**. So to solve the issue you have to remove this file `maintenance.flag` from your server via FTP for exemple.